# SQL HierarchyId - Updating cumulative child values on its parents

Tags: sql-server-2008, hierarchy

I have the following table on SQL Server 2008

[image]

I need to accumulate child Valor field on its respective parents.

Is it possible without loops or recurcive CTEs using hierarchyId functions?

Comment: Besides the odd fact that the sum of whatever valor values you choose is 0, why do you specifically not want to use CTEs, loops or any other solution that works?

Comment: Because I dont know much about the hierarchyId functions and maybe there is a better solution than that one I used to use on SQL Server 2005 (CTEs)